# error! got undefined variable if sent empty post

Tags: php

i got error message if sent empty post in my registration form

**Notice: Undefined index: terms in /opt/lampp/htdocs/user/register.php on line 34**

in the line 34 i have this

```
$terms = trim($_POST["terms"]);
```

and in the form i have this

```
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms"> I have read and accept the conditions of use
</p>
```

and this is all the validation form

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
        $errors       = array();
        $terms        = trim($_POST["terms"]);
        $captcha      = md5($_POST["captcha"]);
    $name         = trim($_POST["name"]);

    if($terms == "")
    {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_SPECIFY_NAME");
    }

    //End data validation
    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {   
            //Construct a user object
            $user = new User($username,$password,$email,$name,$lastname);

            //Checking this flag tells us whether there were any errors such as possible data duplication occured
            if(!$user->status)
            {
                if($user->username_taken) $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_USE",array($username));
                if($user->email_taken)    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_IN_USE",array($email));   
                if($user->email_blocked)  $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_BLOCKED");        
            }
            else
            {
                //Attempt to add the user to the database, carry out finishing  tasks like emailing the user (if required)
                if(!$user->userCakeAddUser())
                {
                    if($user->mail_failure) $errors[] = lang("MAIL_ERROR");
                    if($user->sql_failure)  $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

?>

why i got this alert message?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this:

`if(!empty($_POST))`

with this:

`if(!empty($_POST["terms"]))`

You need to make sure that array **$_POST** has a value with key **terms**

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
$terms        = empty($_POST["terms"]) ? null : trim($_POST["terms"]);
$captcha      = empty($_POST["captcha"]) ? null : md5($_POST["captcha"]);
$name         = empty($_POST["name"]) ? null : trim($_POST["name"]);
```

instead of this:

```
$terms        = trim($_POST["terms"]);
$captcha      = md5($_POST["captcha"]);
$name         = trim($_POST["name"]);
```

Comment: this check only terms value, im corrected the code and i need check more values, all the check values work correctly but this terms not.

Comment: Should I write whole validation process for you? You need to check all keys before access them.

Comment: no, I just wonder if there is any way to fix this without hiding errors.

Comment: Why would you check it 2 times?
only happens with this checkbox in the imput text does not give this error or the select boxes

Comment: If you apply EDIT, you do not need to use previous part of the answer (if you mean this).

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error but a Notice and a notice can be ignored if it’s not critical..

```
if(isset($_POST['terms']))$terms = trim($_POST["terms"]);
```

`isset()` function in PHP determines whether a variable is set and is not NULL. It returns a Boolean value, that is, if the variable is set it will return true and if the variable value is null it will return false.

You can also turn off notices by using

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

in the start of your script..

Comment: i'm corrected but i cant do this, because im check more values

Comment: you need to validate user input..for erroneous or malicious inputs and also for blank inputs to avoid bot entries..here we are checking that before applying `trim` function..